# Something wrong with passport.authenticate()

Tags: node.js, axios, passport.js

In my register API I am sending data using axios from reactjs. My user is getting saved at backend but still I am getting 400 Bad Request Error. My console.log inside passport is not working means I think something is wrong with passport.authenticate(). Please help.

```
 app.post("/register",(req,res)=>{

    User.register(new User({username: 
    req.body.params.data.username}),req.body.params.data.password,function(err,user){
        if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
     passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
    console.log(user);
    })    
    })
   });
```

Comment: Probably your use of authenticate inside the callback of route function is what might be causing the problem.